# AWS Lambda Concurrency with different context

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that evaluates each stock. 
The first instance of the lambda will process stock A, B, C
The second instance of the lambda will process stock E, F, G
The third instance of the lambda will process stock X, Y, Z. 
...

How do I set this up in AWS, I only want to keep one lambda in AWS. Or is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this by using a Lambda function to split the job and trigger subsequent Lambdas. This can be done either using a Single Lambda function to self invoke (With a different functional flow) or invoke a second Lambda function to do the the processing.

[image]

Reference: [AWS re:Invent 2016: Serverless Architectural Patterns and Best Practices (ARC402)](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/aws-reinvent-2016-serverless-architectural-patterns-and-best-practices-arc402)